# Why isn't the data modeling in the view

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to build a datepicker calendar app but I can't seem to get either the view component working.
The data is showing up in the Ember Inspector but the view component is blank. I've been reviewing site after site I just can't seem to see where it's going wrong.

```
<body>  
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <div id="navbar">
       <ul>
        <li>{{#link-to "calendar"}}Calendar{{/link-to}}</li>
        <li>{{#link-to "about"}}About{{/link-to}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content"> {{outlet}} </div>
    </div>
    <footer id='container'>Footer information here!</footer>   

  </script>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="about">
    <h1>About</h1>
    <p>My calendar Date picker!</>
  </script>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="calendar">
    <h1>Calendar Page</h1>
    <button>Next</button>
    <button>Today</button>
    <button>Back</button>
    <hr>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr><td>{{name}}</td></tr>
      </thead>
        {{#each months}}
          <tr><td>{{days}}</tr></td>
        {{else}}
          No data.
        {{/each}}
    </tabel>
    <hr>
  </script>


App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource("calendar");
    this.resource("about");     
});


App.CalendarRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return months;
    }
});


// calendar controller
App.CalendarController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({});

// calendar data
 var months = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'January',
        days: 31
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Febuary',
        days: 28
    }, {
        id: 3,
        name: 'March',
        days: 31
    }, {
        id: 4,
        name: 'April',
        days: 30
    }, {
        id: 5,
        name: 'May',
        days: 31
    }, {
        id: 6,
        name: 'June',
        days: 30
    }, {
        id: 7,
        name: 'July',
        days: 31
    }, {
        id: 8,
        name: 'August',
        days: 31
    }, {
        id: 9,
        name: 'September',
        days: 30
    }, {
        id: 10,
        name: 'October',
        days: 31
    }, {
        id: 11,
        name: 'November',
        days: 30
    }, {
        id: 12,
        name: 'December',
        days: 31
    }];

var days = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Monday'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Tuesday'
    }, {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Wednesday'
    }, {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Thursday'
    }, {
        id: 5,
        name: 'Friday'
    }, {
        id: 6,
        name: 'Saturday'
    }, {
        id: 7,
        name: 'Sunday'
    }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The templates are fine, all views are rendered as they should

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/surozime/1/edit

maybe you are missing the required routes,

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("application");
  this.route("about");
  this.route("calendar");
});
```

**edit** - *response to comments*

To be honest didn't pay much attention to the content of the templates, there were couple of errors that caused this.

**1**.no closing tag for element `p` in template `about` (there was a syntax `</>`).

**2**.no closing tag for element `table` in template `calendar` (there was a syntax `</tabel>`).

**3**.associated orphan `{{else}}` that was within the `{{each}}`, with an `{{if}}`.

updated example,
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/surozime/4/edit

**hbs** *(corrected)*

```
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <div id="navbar">
       <ul>
        <li>{{#link-to "calendar"}}Calendar{{/link-to}}</li>
        <li>{{#link-to "about"}}About{{/link-to}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content"> {{outlet}} </div>
    </div>
    <footer id='container'>Footer information here!</footer>   

  </script>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="about">
    <h1>About</h1>
    <p>My calendar Date picker!</p>
  </script>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="calendar">
    <h1>Calendar Page</h1>
    <button>Next</button>
    <button>Today</button>
    <button>Back</button>
    <hr>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr><td>{{name}}</td></tr>
      </thead>
      {{#if months}}
        {{#each months}}
          <tr><td>{{days}}</tr></td>
        {{/each}}
        {{else}}
          No data.
        {{/if}}
    </table>
    <hr>
  </script>
```

Comment: Ok but why does it keep appending the view?

Comment: @LineyHamilton you are right, did not notice that :) , i just provided an updated link with corrected syntax errors related to the templates.

Comment: Awesome... does the If statement fix that?

Comment: @LineyHamilton yes correcting the syntax errors related to html and handlebars, the three points shown in the answer, fixes it.